# Get all properties from yago using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf

I want to retrieve all properties from yago which is an RDFS knowledge base(.nt format).I tried with
bellow query

```
SELECT distinct ?x WHERE { ?y ?x ?z . }
```

This gives me all the predicates.

[image: Sample output of 1st query]

In the web they defined predicates as predicates(properties). According to this my result should be correct. But my professor suggested me bellow query

```
SELECT distinct ?x WHERE { ?y ?x ?z . ?z a ?zt. }
```

He didn't explain the reason. The results are a little bit different for this 2 query. The result of the 2nd query is a subset of 1st query. Does it mean more precise?

[image: sample output of 2nd query]

Can anyone help me understand why he added `?z a ?zt .`? Will the object used to obtain properties always be `rdf:type` of a different class?

Comment: What is the number of triples return by these two examples? And can you provide examples of triples return by the first query but not by the second query?

Comment: Yes, the second query is constraining `?z` to be in `rdf:type` relation with something else. It is not clear why this should be a better solution, could have you misread the assignment?

Comment: the second query would even omit data properties, i.e. where the object (here `?z`) is a literal. (modulo indeed dataset or inference where RDFS axiomatic triples like `lit rdf:type rdfs:Literal` would exists, which is not the case for the YAGO dataset). It also restricts it to predicates used to relate objects where a type exists. That"s also not always the case (again modulo RDFS axiomatic triples and/or inference)

Comment: I have provided some sample output. Can you kindly check again? @OrtomalaLokni

Comment: Knowing the number of returned triples is useless, as well as the example required by @OrtomalaLokni. We don't need to know the underlying data for understanding that the first query contains the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [RDF 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#data-model):

> The core structure of the abstract syntax is a set of triples, each consisting of a subject, a predicate and an object.
>
> [...]
>
> The predicate itself is an IRI and denotes a **property**, that is, a resource that can be thought of as a binary relation.

According to these definitions, you can get all properties in SPARQL with your first request:

```
SELECT distinct ?x WHERE { ?y ?x ?z . }
```

The second request is more specific:

```
SELECT distinct ?x WHERE { ?y ?x ?z . ?z a ?zt. }
```

It lists all properties used at least once in a triple where the object is also involved in a `rdf:type` triple as a subject.

Note that in SPARQL `a` is a [shortcut](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#abbrevRdfType) for `rdf:type`.